# Pass this component to arrow function [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass this component created with 'class' to 'arrow functions' but I'm new in React and JavaScript so I still can't get it, could someone help me?

```
const cookies = new Cookies();
 class Index extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    token: cookies.get('token') || null
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You mean converting the class component to functional component(Arrow Function)?

Comment: yes, that's what i want!

Comment: Check this out: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 types of components in React
1.Class Based Components and 2. Functional Components
you can convert a class based component to functional component using arrow function

you can write the above class based component into functional component as follows

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const index=()=>{
const [cookies, setCookies] = useState(cookies.get('token') || null);
return(
    <div>
        
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `useState` should be inside the functional component, you might mislead someone!

Answer (score 0):

After importing and using the `useState` hook you can do one of these:

```js
function Index(props) {
    const [cookies, setCookies] = useState(cookies.get('token') || null);
    // do stuff and return something
}
```

or

```js
const Index = (props) => {
    const [cookies, setCookies] = useState(cookies.get('token') || null);
    // do stuff and return something
}
```